# C++ code generation from XML

Tags: c++, xml, code-generation

I would like to be able to specify the layout of different packets in a client server protocol in XML, and at (or before) compile time, have that XML be parsed and C++ code be generated to parse the defined layouts.

Example:

```
<layout>
    <opcode id=1>
        <field type=uint32 label="itemId" />
        <field type=uint8 label="count" />
        <field type=strlen32 label="name" />
    </opcode>
</layout>
```

Bad XML not withstanding, and whereby 'strlen32' would mean a string whose 32 bit length prefixes the content, would produce the following handler upon processing:

```
void Handle_Opcode1(Packet &packet, std::function<...> emitter)
{
    std::uint32_t itemId = packet.Read<std::uint32_t>();
    std::uint8_t count = packet.Read<std::uint8_t>();
    std::uint32_t nameLen = packet.Read<std::uint32_t>();
    std::vector<char> name(static_cast<std::size_t>(nameLen));
    packet.Read(&name[0], name.size());

    emitter(itemId, count, name);
}
```

I don't know exactly how I would want the emitter to work in a generic way, but I consider that beyond the scope of this question.  Presently I am just searching for recommendations on the C++ code generation.  Are there any existing tools to do this?

Comment: _"Are there any existing tools to do this?"_ Yes, it's called XSLT.

Comment: These kind of questions are explicitly _off-topic_ here. Read point #4 from this [help center article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: As written this is pretty off topic, but it's not that hard to do this using XSLT - see if you can come up with a more specific question about how to do it with XSLT once you've looked at doing it and if you're having any challenges.

Comment: Are you changing code dynamically or *data*?

Comment: This is a quick and very incomplete example of how XSLT might be used... http://xsltransform.net/gWEamM9

Comment: I'm sorry.  You're right re: off-topic.  It wasn't my intention to ignore the rules!

Comment: @namreeb Well, XSLT is _the tool_ to do such. There aren't any reasonable others.

Comment: Thank you.  I apparently I am not considered qualified to say thank you, or mark your reply as the answer, but if I could I would.